# $f(x)$ not continous at 0 but $f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ continuous at 0: Is my example valid?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I'm but a lowly electrical engineering student interested in mathematics. Recently, I've been working through the second edition of Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* and I encountered a problem that I'm not entirely sure about, specifically problem 4.3.6, part d, which states:

Provide an example or explain why the request is impossible: A function $f(x)$ which is not continuous at 0 such that $f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is continuous at 0.

Now, being supremely lazy, my instinct at first was to say, "sure, consider the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x \neq 0$}
\end{cases}"$$
Then, my reasoning was that the only way we can define $g(x) = f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is via the restriction of $f$ onto the domain $\{0\}$. So, since 0 is clearly an isolated point in the domain of $g$, it follows that $g(x)$ must be continuous at 0.

Does this answer fit the "spirit" of the question? Or am I only allowed to choose an $f$ such that $g$ can have the same domain as $f$? Thanks for your help!

Comment: For that $f$ we have that ${1\over f(x)}$ is not defined anywhere except at $0$.

Comment: This looks like evading the question. It's not too hard to tweak this example to a genuine example, though.

Comment: Solve f(x)=-1/f(x).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f$ be given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}C&,x>0\\\\\frac1C&,x\le0\end{cases}$$

where $C\ne1$, $C\ne 0$.

Comment: Oh wow, that's definitely a better way to do it that I didn't think of at all. But I'm still curious whether my example is technically correct or not.

Comment: Aka the best kind of correct.

Comment: Your solution won't work since $1/0$ is undefined.

Comment: lol if they were a coward I'm sure they would be too scared to respond (not me i upvoted chill)

Comment: So basically, if you're defining a function as the sum of two others, it's required that all three have the same domain?

Comment: @sakethmalyal Thank you my friend!  I really appreciate the up vote and your sense of humor too!

Comment: @elduderino Well, we're looking for a discontinuous function that when added to its reciprocal becomes continuous.  The common domain is implicit.

Comment: @Mark Alright, thanks for your help! I've up voted and accepted your answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Pleased this was useful.  And thank you for the recognition!  Much appreciated.